# Multilingual theme: Changing locale based on URL

Tags: url-rewriting, multi-language

I'm developing a multilangual theme. I use the __() function for translation, which works just fine.
The main language is English, but the second language is German. For that second language, I'd like to add an "/de/"-Slug, so I created a rewrite rule:

```
function rewrite_rule_de(){
    add_rewrite_rule('de/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&language=de', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_rule_de');
```

As you can see, I also added a get-variable (language=de), which should tell Wordpress, that the page being displayed is German. Because Wordpress doesn't simply process this get-variable, I added it to query_vars:

```
function language_query_var($public_query_vars){
    $public_query_vars[] = 'language';  
    return $public_query_vars;  
}
add_action('query_vars', 'language_query_var');
```

I want to change the locale, based on the language of the page beeing displayed, so I use the following function:

```
function set_my_locale( $lang ){
  if ('de' == get_query_var('language')){
    return 'de_DE';
  }else{
    return 'en_US';
  }
}
add_filter('locale', 'set_my_locale');
```

My problem here is that get_query_var('language') isn't defined in the function "set_my_locale". But it works when used before the loop, for example...

So my question is simply: How can I change the locale (so that the __()-function outputs the proper language) based on a rewrite-rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem here is that `get_query_var('language')` isn't defined in the function `set_my_locale`

Because `get_locale` (which applies the filter `locale`) is called before `wp()` (which parses the query & sets up the variables).

You'll have to manually inspect the request yourself:

```
if ( strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/de/' ) === 0 ) {
    // German
} else {
    // English
}
```

Note this expects WordPress to be running under the root URL i.e. http://example.com/

Comment: A possible work-around for the root issue is split the request URI into an array using `explode` and then checking if the language is in the array. Of course, this is entirely theoretical so YMMV.

Comment: I would probably opt to use the logic in `WP::parse_request()`, since it's a more rigorous check (ensures `de` isn't simply lingering *anywhere* in the URI fragment), but since it's an isolated case I chose to KISS ;)

Comment: Thanks - although this seems a bit non-standardised. Thought there would be a more "wordpress-like" way of doing this...