# Locale switching with a "language" taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, multi-language, language

I know that it's possible to switch the WP locale by using URL paramaters, [as described here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59517/multilingual-theme-changing-locale-based-on-url), but I'm trying to build a method that would entirely rely on a custom "Language" taxonomy.

What I currently have is a simple plugin, that registers the language taxonomy and implements a locale switch if the taxonomy is present:

```
<?php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpsx_register_taxonomies' );
function wpsx_register_taxonomies() {
register_taxonomy('wpsx_language', array (
                  0 => 'post',
                  1 => 'page',
                ), array( 
                    'hierarchical' => true, 
                    'label' => 'Languages',
                    'singular_label' => 'Language',
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'rewrite' => false,
                    ) 
                );
}
function wpsx_redefine_locale($locale) {
    global $post;
      if ( taxonomy_exists( 'wpsx_language' )) {
        $locale = 'de_DE'; // this does work !!
        if ( has_term( 'fr', 'wpsx_language' )) {
            $locale = 'fr_FR'; // this does not work yet :(
        }   
     }
     return $locale;
}
add_filter('locale','wpsx_redefine_locale',10);
?>
```

So the little part that isn't working is the `has_term()` test. My impression is that the locale filter is running at an early step in the loading sequence, when the post content isn't retrieved yet, and therefore conditional tests like `is_single()` or `has_term()` won't return anything.

Can I force the post content to load earlier? Can I delay the locale filter?

I'm unable to figure out a solution for this. On the wp-hackers mailing list, a suggestion was to run `global $post;` but this didn't help.

---

**Update:** following the suggestion by david.binda, I found a workaround, dropping the taxonomy, and using the post slug as a trigger:

```
function wpsx89972_redefine_locale($locale) {
    $wpsx_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $wpsx_url_lang = substr($wpsx_url, -4); // test for the last 4 chars:
    if ( $wpsx_url_lang == "-fr/") {
        $locale = 'fr_FR';
    } else if ( $wpsx_url_lang == "-en/") { 
        $locale = 'en_US';
    } else { // fallback to default
        $locale = 'de_DE'; 
    }
    return $locale;
}
add_filter('locale','wpsx89972_redefine_locale',10);
```

This requires the user to rewrite the post slugs, such as "my-post-title-fr" for French, "my-post-title-en" for English, etc. A bit less user-friendly than using language tickboxes, but it keeps the code simple and just works.

So now I have a functional multi-language plugin, in only 13 lines of code :)

Still, I will leave this question open for a couple days, to see if anyone comes up with a solution that would make use of the taxonomy...

Comment: You don't have to relly on user's input to post slug. You can keep the taxonomy box on and hook into save_post action and based on term assigned, rewrite the slug: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post#Caution.21

Comment: Right, maybe I will do that, if I find some good sample code :)

Comment: See my updated answer below

Comment: Did you ever get the theme loading the correct mo files with this? I'm checking  if a post is in a specific category or that category terms listing page and changing to locale. It changes the document language and the core es_ES mo file loads, but plugins and theme still load the default language

Comment: @RobertWent with the Category as a criteria to change the locale, you are facing the same issue I had with a taxonomy: the Post content is loaded too late, and you need to find a trick to test for the Category earlier in the process. I think the solution by Fahad Alduraibi below can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Manu interesting. It is detecting the category fine as the html language changes just for posts in that category. I assumed when it ran was dependent on the filter used. I'm tempted to just use Fahad's plugin now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [url_to_postid](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) function

Used as follows from your wpsx_redefine_locale function:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$postid = url_to_postid( $url );
```

Note that this does not return the post id for custom post types but the function is located in /wp-includes/rewrite.php and might be extended if needed.

**UPDATE**: here's your sample:

```
function my_function(){
if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action('save_post', 'my_function');

    // update the post, which calls save_post again
    $my_post_args = array();
    $my_post_args['ID'] = post_id;
    $p = get_post( $post_id );
    $lang_tax = 'my_lang_tax_name';
    $language_terms = get_post_terms( $post_id, $lang_tax );
    $my_post_args['post_name'] = $p->name . '_' . $language_terms[0]->slug;
    wp_update_post( $my_post_args );

    // re-hook this function
    add_action('save_post', 'my_function');
}
add_action('save_posts', 'my_function');
```

What have to be done further, but that's up to you. You have to sanitize the situation when user changed language taxonomy term assigned to post, so you don't get `my-post_de_en` instead of `my-post_en` on post which was before in de and had `my-post_de` slug. This would require some regular expressions stuff, but you'll manage that ;)

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. What's the implied reasoning - to retrieve the post ID, then to make a raw database query to check for the taxonomy? Unfortunately, url_to_postid() doesn't work that early in the action chain. If I include it in the locale filter, it generates a "Fatal error: Call to a member function wp_rewrite_rules() on a non-object". If I call it at a later step, it works fine.

Comment: was worth trying... wp_rewrite is defined later, apparently. I'm afraid I'm out of further ideas.

Comment: After all, your suggestion made me think, and I noticed that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` part was at least returning the post URL... I guess there's a reason why all existing multilanguage plugins rely on the URL. So I'm now settling for a workaround, using the last part of the URL string to switch the language, like "my-post-title-fr", "my-post-title-en", etc. A compromise, but at least it works and keeps things simple.

Comment: Oh wow, that's a great code sample! I will build upon that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution that will not change anything in your post, but will only add a meta

```
// Set the post language when loading up the page based on the store meta
function ppl_set_post_language() {
    $postID = url_to_postid( $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] );
    if ($postID > 0) {
        $postLanguage = esc_attr( get_post_meta( $postID, '_ppl_post_language', true ) );
        if ( ! empty( $postLanguage ) ) {
            global $locale;
            $locale = $postLanguage;
        }
    }
}
// Any call to 'url_to_postid' earlier then 'setup_theme' will generate a fatal error.
add_action('setup_theme', 'ppl_set_post_language');
```

For more details check my answer (on my own question) here: [Set language per post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/222469/set-language-per-post/223596#223596)

And I have a plugin that makes everything for you (link is in my answer also)